# Unable to unzip the web service response in Linux using java

Tags: java, web-services

We are executing web services using java code. The web service response comes in gzip format from the web service provider. We are unzipping the response using GZIPInputStream after receiving the response.

Response is converted into byte codes and then passing as input to gzipinputstream. This code is working fine in Eclipse and able to unzip the response string. The same code is not working in Linux and throwing the error "Not in Gzip format" while passing the byte array to gzipinputstream.

We checked the default charset in Windows is windows-1252 and in Linux is UTF-8. So, we tried to get the bytes in UTF-8 and windows-1252. Both are not working.

Can anyone please help me where is it going wrong and how to resolve the issue?

Tried changing the charset while generating the byte codes of the response.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io. * ;
import java.nio.charset.*;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
import java.nio.charset.*;

public class WSConnectTest {

    public final static String UserName = null; //User id login for Fusion
    public final static String instanceURL = null;
    public final static String USER_PWD = null; // API key shared by CSOD

    private static final String PROXY_URL = null; //UBS proxy URL
    private static final int PROXY_PORT = 8080;
    private static final String PROXY_USERNAME = "USER_NAME";
    private static final String PROXY_PASSWORD = "PASSWORD";
    final static String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    static Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(
    PROXY_URL, PROXY_PORT));

    static {
        Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return (new PasswordAuthentication(UserName, USER_PWD.toCharArray()));
            }
        };
        Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        FusionConnect fusionconnect = new FusionConnect();

        String theURL = instanceURL + "<RESOURCE_NAME>";
        System.out.println("The URL to be called is : " + theURL);
        String json = "<JSON_STRING>"
        String post_param = new String(json.toString());
        System.out.println("The json is :" + json);

        PostRequestWithFilter(theURL, post_param);

    }

    private static void PostRequestWithFilter(String url, String json) throws Exception {

        try {

            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection(proxy);

            con.setRequestMethod("POST");

            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "UTF-8");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            con.setDoOutput(true);

            con.setConnectTimeout(15000);

            System.out.println("get content type :"+con.getRequestProperties());

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());

            wr.writeBytes(json);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
            System.out.println("\nResponse Code : " + responseCode);
            System.out.println("\nResponse message : " + con.getResponseMessage());

            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            String ResponseStr = null;
            byte[] bresponse = new byte[1024];
            String deoutput = null;
            BufferedReader in =null;
            if (responseCode == con.HTTP_CREATED) { in =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                                        response.append(inputLine);
                                        System.out.println("Response received from Fusion string buffer :"+inputLine);
                                } in .close();

                                ResponseStr = response.toString();
                                System.out.println("response string :"+ResponseStr);
                                bresponse = ResponseStr.getBytes("UTF-8");
                                System.out.println("Response received from Fusion Bytes :"+bresponse);
                                deoutput = unzip(bresponse);
                                System.out.println("Decompressed response :"+deoutput);
            } else { in =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getErrorStream()));

                System.out.println("Response Content Type :"+con.getContentType());
                System.out.println("Response Content Encoding :"+con.getContentEncoding());

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine+"\r");
                    System.out.println("Response received from Fusion string buffer :"+inputLine);
                } 
                in .close();

                ResponseStr = response.toString();
                System.out.println("response string :"+response);
                bresponse = ResponseStr.getBytes();

                for (int i=0; i < bresponse.length; i++)
                {
                 System.out.println("byte code :"+i+" "+bresponse[i]);
                }           

                System.out.println("Response received from Fusion Bytes :"+Charset.defaultCharset()+bresponse);
                deoutput = unzip(bresponse);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("fileName1.gz");
                DataOutputStream outStream = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fos));
                outStream.writeUTF(ResponseStr);
                outStream.close();

                System.out.println("Decompressed response :"+deoutput);
            } 
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
    public static String unzip(byte[] compressed) {
        if ((compressed == null) || (compressed.length == 0)) {
            System.out.println("The response is empty");
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot unzip null or empty bytes");
        }
        if (!isZipped(compressed)) {
            System.out.println("The response is not zipped");
            return new String(compressed);
        }

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        try (ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed)) {
                    System.out.println("After byte array input stream :");
            try (GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(byteArrayInputStream)) {
                try (InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(byteArrayInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)){
                    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)) {
                        String line;
                        System.out.println("buffer reader :"+bufferedReader.readLine());
                        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            output.append(line);
                            System.out.println("line :"+output.toString());
                        }
                    } catch(IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to read bufferedReader content", e);
                        }
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return output.toString();
    }
    public static boolean isZipped(final byte[] compressed) {
        System.out.println("(byte)(GZIPInputStream.GZIP_MAGIC) is "+(byte)(GZIPInputStream.GZIP_MAGIC));
        System.out.println("gzip magic is "+(byte)(GZIPInputStream.GZIP_MAGIC >> 8));
        return (compressed[0] == (byte)(GZIPInputStream.GZIP_MAGIC)) && (compressed[1] == (byte)(GZIPInputStream.GZIP_MAGIC >> 8));
    }
}
```

Comment: If the response is gzip, why are you reading it into a string? What is the content type?

Comment: Hi Kai, I printed the stream and it's still in compressed format.

Comment: and now I see that you check that before trying.

Comment: Hi RealSkeptic, Please suggest me any other way to read the response. The content type is "application/json".